# Do I have any rights if PayPal permanently suspend my account?

Tags: united-kingdom, finance

I recently had a message from PayPal telling me that my account has been permanently suspended due to 'unacceptable risk'.
I have only ever used it to make small payments to eBay and such, and I have a maximum credit score on Experian. So there must be some mistake. The 'permanently' language is pretty obnoxious. I logged into my account to check and this is legitimate and not phishing

What kind of rights do I have in this situation? Do I have a right to an explanation of what the 'unacceptable risk' is?
Do I have a right to know whether this decision was made by a human being or by an automated system? (It looks pretty much definitely automated to me)
Do I have a right to have a human being review the decision?
Do I have any other relevant rights that may be helpful for for me to know about before ringing Paypal to discuss this?

I live in the UK.

Edit;
o.m. pointed out in the comments that if I am with the EU subsidiary of PayPal then the situation may be different as PayPal is considered a bank in this jurisdiction. It looks like this is the case and I am registered with the EU version

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't a phising mail?

Comment: There is certainly a common phishing scam where people are notified that their PayPal account is suspended or otherwise suspicious and they need to provide all kinds of information to keep it open "send passport and bank details!" But it doesn't sound like this is happening here. Nonetheless, I would have to ask what PayPal's terms and conditions say.

Comment: @PMF yes, I edited my post.

Comment: Are there any funds that they are holding and not releasing?

Comment: @Acccumulation thankfully not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the terms: https://www.paypal.com/uk/legalhub/useragreement-full#resolving

> These are the terms and conditions of the contract between you and
> PayPal (Europe) S.à r.l. et Cie, S.C.A. (“PayPal”) governing your use
> of your PayPal account and the PayPal services, which we call our user
> agreement. It applies only to PayPal accounts of residents of the
> United Kingdom (UK), Guernsey, Isle of Man and Jersey.

PayPal is a private business; the terms you agreed to allow them to  suspend your account for any of the many listed reasons and stipulations in the terms. (As long as that reason is itself isn't illegal, such as discrimination against protected classes, breaking clear financial laws, etc.)

You may get some help from https://www.gov.uk/consumer-protection-rights

Comment: Prove that they can suspend your account for any reason simply because they are a private business.

Comment: So I read from your answer: I have no rights, CAB might give me some advice, and I can use making a complaint to the ombudsman as leverage if I need to?

Comment: @paulj do you have evidence that this is not the case in practice?

Comment: In the EU, paypal is also a bank and subject to additional oversight over how they conduct their business. Would be interesting to know *which* paypal subsidiary the OP has a contract with.

Comment: Luxemburg is a country in the EU

Comment: UK is not EU anymore; read my edit to my answer.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch great, thanks Brexit...

Comment: @Joe Sorry, but you are bound by the contract you signed. The terms says PayPal can do anything it wants with your account, as long as it's not illegal to do. Just about any sort of service contact out there is the same; once you sign or agree, they have little to no liability.

Comment: In the UK [banks can close your account with 30 days notice for any/no reason](https://www.thisismoney.co.uk/money/saving/article-11307809/Can-Barclays-close-current-account-without-giving-reason.html) but I guess you'd need evidence that this applies to PayPal as well as conventional accounts. Read the fine print.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch “for any reason” - like because I’m black? Or not black?